# Choroplet map with folium

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, folium, choropleth

```
import os
import folium
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = 'https://cocl.us'
state_geo = f'{url}/san-francisco.geojson'
state_crime = f'{url}/sanfran_crime_dataset'
state_data = pd.read_csv(state_crime)
state_data.rename(columns={'PdDistrict':'District'},inplace = True)
state_data['count']= state_data.groupby('District')['District'].transform('count')

m = folium.Map(location=[37.76, -122.45], zoom_start=3)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=state_geo,
    name='choropleth',
    data=state_data,
    columns=['District', 'count'],
    key_on='feature.properties.DISTRICT',
    fill_color='YlGn',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Crime Rate(%)'
).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

This is my code, I want to display a choropleth map about crime data in San Francisco, but it displays me an error:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I check the ID's and all the data was organized to match with the geodata file
the columns are with the exact same name.

Thanks for the time you spend reading my code and trying to help me.

Comment: The url for your geojson file gives *404 This page could not be found.* In order to make your issue reproducible, please provide the geojson file somehow.